# Firebase RTDB: How exactly the 2nd argument of cursors(startAt, endAt...) work?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

code:

```
import {
  orderByValue,
  ref,
  getDatabase,
  set,
  get,
  query,
  startAfter
} from "firebase/database";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const app = initializeApp({
  projectId: "some-id"
});

const db = getDatabase();

const testRun = async () => {
  await set(ref(db), { d: 5, y: 4, b: 6, m: 0, p: 1 });
  const snapshot = await get(
    query(ref(db), orderByValue(), startAfter(0, "b"))
  );
  console.log(snapshot.val());
};

testRun();
```

result:`{b: 6, d: 5, m: 0, p: 1, y: 4}`

how is this make sense? with `startAfter(0, 'b')`, I was expecting the result to be `{d: 5, p: 1, y: 4}`, but that is not totally the case.

**what make thing even confusing is, the result includes `m:0`!!**

however if I go with `startAfter(0)`, the result is `{b: 6, d: 5, p: 1, y: 4}` which is expected.

how exactly does the 2nd argument work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understand how it works

first we order according to the orderBy clause, in this case we order by value

```
{ 
  m: 0, 
  p: 1,
  y: 4, 
  d: 5, 
  b: 6 
}
```

to understand what `startAfter(0,'b')` return, we simply imagine where `b:0` would be located

```
{ 
  b: 0, // imagine
  m: 0, 
  p: 1,
  y: 4, 
  d: 5, 
  b: 6 
}
```

since `b` come before `m`, so everything after `b:0` is what we will get, which is everything

with the same logic, we can deduce what `endAt(6, 'd')` return

```
{ 
  m: 0, 
  p: 1,
  y: 4, 
  d: 5, 
  b: 6 
  d: 6, // imagine
}
```

the result would be also everything

the trick is to know where the reference point is

Answer (score 1):

The second value you specify to `startAfter` (and its sibling methods) is typically used as a so-called disambiguation key, in case there are multiple child nodes with the value that you pass in the first argument. It is *only* applied after the filter on the regular value has been executed.

When we order your data by value, we get:

```
{ 
  m: 0, 
  p: 1,
  y: 4, 
  d: 5, 
  b: 6 
}
```

Since there's only one node with value `0`, the database returns all nodes after that one.

Comment: but the result of `startAfter(0, 'b')` includes `m:0`, how come?

Comment: also if the 2nd argument only apply after the first filter, shouldn't the result be `{}` because `b` is the last key in that order?

Comment: #1) My guess is that, since `b` is before `m`, it includes `m` in the result. So it would only skip the exact node with value `0` and key `b`. #2) No, it first orders/filters on the value, which leads it to your `"m": 0` node as the only possible starting pint.